# Extract error message from custom error specified with expect

Tags: rust

I am learning about error handling in rust

I want to extract out the error message `"Something went wrong"` in the parent function and print it out

```rust
fn parent_function() {
    let username =  read_username_from_file("wtf.txt");
    if let Ok(username) = username {
        println!("{}", username);
    } else if let Err(username) = username{
        println!("{}", username.to_string()); // this prints out the raw message
                                              // I only want what I passed in expect 
    }
}

fn read_username_from_file(filename: &str) -> Result<String, io::Error> {
    let mut file = File::open(filename).expect("Something went wrong");
    let mut username = String::new();
    file.read_to_string(&mut username).unwrap();
    return Ok(username);
}
```

Also, is there a neater/cleaner way to handle username / error message from the parent function dealing with Result<String, Error>?

Comment: Just so that it's very clear, your `println!("{}", username.to_string())` was never running, the program was printing due to the panic.

Answer (score 0):

The [`.expect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.expect) method causes the program to panic, what you want instead is the [question mark `?`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/#the-question-mark-operator-) operator, which will exit the function early if the result is an error.

```rust
let mut file = File::open(filename)?;
```

Since you want to use a custom error message instead of the error provided by `File::open`, you can use the [`.map_err()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err) method, which accepts a function (I provide a closure).

```rust
let mut file = File::open(filename)
    .map_err(|_| io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, "something went wrong!"))?;
// This will erase some information about what happened, 
//     but is nice if you just want a message
```

Additionally, `std::io` provides a helper type [`io::Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/type.Result.html) which is conventionally used instead of `Result<T, io::Error>`. The final function can look something like:

```rust
fn read_username_from_file(filename: &str) -> io::Result<String> {
    let mut file = File::open(filename)
        .map_err(|_| io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, "something went wrong!"))?;
    let mut username = String::new();
    // you may also not want to unwrap here, since this also panics.
    // you can use the same .map_err strategy :)
    file.read_to_string(&mut username).unwrap();
    return Ok(username);
}
```

As for handling the error in `parent_function()`, a match block allows you to handle all variants of an enum cleanly.

```rust
fn parent_function() {
    match read_username_from_file("wtf.txt") {
        Ok(username) => println!("username is: {username}"),
        Err(e) => println!("oh no!!! {e:?}"),
    }
}
```

Comment: This explains alot, but this code is throwing error at line two in read_username_from_file function at into() saying "type annotations needed"?

Comment: You're right, I updated my answer, I thought that io::Error had a conversion from &str. :p